# Perl write to pathfile, then send using unix's mail

Tags: perl, email

I'm trying to write a Perl script which writes to a file and then uses linux's mail command to send whatever the Perl script wrote to the file.
My code is the following:

```
my $pathfile='some_pathfile';
open(W_VAR,">>$pathfile");
print W_VAR 'hello';
close W_VAR;

my $email_command='mail -s'." header".' some_email_address'.' <'." $pathfile";
system($email_command);
```

The problem is that the content in the pathfile never gets sent.
If I personally fill out that file, all is fine, but whatever perl has written is simply not sent. The content is in the file when i check though.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code that you actually use.

Comment: try `open(W_VAR, ">>", "$pathfile") || printf( "can't open %s\n", $filepath );` - see if you get an error

Comment: seems like you are missing a closing single quote on the first line

Comment: I added that single quote. still doesn't work.

Comment: @scibuff i tried that. no problem reported on writing to the file. and it seems like it writes to the file, its just that the email script doesn't "see" whatever the perl script wrote to the file.

Comment: @Joni that would make the question more complex and make it include lots of information irrelevant to the problem. I managed to narrow the problem down to this.

Comment: how about `echo | mutt -a filename email_addr` instead of `mail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your program doesn't terminate the line with a newline `"\n"` character. No doubt you put one into the file when you edited it manually?

Something like this may fix it, but I don't have a Linux box to hand so I can't test it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pathfile = 'path/to/file';
open my $w_var, '>>', $pathfile or die $!;
print $w_var "Hello\nWorld!\n";
close $w_var;

my $email_command = "mail -s header some\@emailaddress.com < $pathfile";
system $email_command;
```

---

**Edit**

But it would be far nicer to use something like [Mail::Sendmail](https://metacpan.org/module/Mail%3a%3aSendmail). [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender) is by far the best, but together with its dependencies it is a huge module for so simple a task and I hesitate to recommend it here.

The code to use `Mail::Sendmail` would look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mail::Sendmail;

my $pathfile = 'path/to/file';

open my $w_var, '>>', $pathfile or die $!;
print $w_var "Hello\n", "World!\n";

my $message = do {
  open $w_var, '<', $pathfile or die $!;
  local $/;
  <$w_var>;
};

sendmail(
  To => 'some@emailaddress.com',
  From => 'my.address@email.com',
  Message => $message,
)
or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;
```

Comment: It definitely was the newline. Apparently the newline operator is more that what one would naturally think it is.. a-new-line. Confusing.

Comment: +1 for `Email::Sender` provides a really nice object oriented interface.

Comment: @Nikhil Jain: it's a very nice tools, but oh those dependencies! `Capture::Tiny` `Carp` `Cwd` `Email::Abstract` `Email::Address` `Email::Simple` `Fcntl` `File::Basename` `File::Find` `File::Path` `File::Spec` `File::Temp` `FindBin` `List::MoreUtils` `Moose` `Net::SMTP` `Scalar::Util` `Sys::Hostname` `Throwable::Error` `Try::Tiny`.  `Moose` on its own is huge . . .

Comment: @Hermann Ingjaldsson: think of a newline in a file as being like pressing *Enter* when entering the text manually. Without it the program doesn't see the preceding data.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that your command is not well formed:

Try:

```
my $header = "My Subject";
my $some_email_address = "myaccount@myemail.com";
my $email_command="mail -s \"$header\" $some_email_address < $pathfile";
```